# Como podria resolver " error TS2305: Module " primeNG

Tags: angular8, primeng

Estoy realizando un filtrado de datos en tablas con "primeng" y me sale el siguiente error
**error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/MSI/Documents/projects/salas/node_modules/primeng/api/primeng-api"' has no exported member 'FilterUtils'.**
y la verdad desconozco el porque, gracias.

```
import {FilterUtils} from 'primeng/api';
```

```
    FilterUtils['custom-equals'] = (value, filter): boolean => {
      if (filter === undefined || filter === null || filter.trim() === '') {
          return true;
      }

      if (value === undefined || value === null) {
          return false;
      }

      return value.toString() === filter.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la respuesta.

```
import {FilterUtils} from 'primeng/utils';
```

En lugar de /api es /utils